# Joining tables, Total order price based on a DATE and getting 2 separate sums of different dates records instead of 1 which is not unique to date

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a reservation/order system where employees create reservations for customers. Each reservation is a new `Reservation_id` they manually assign tables and know what table is reserved for a specific date. Now I am working on a way to let the personnel take orders from customers, this is not based on their `Reservation_id` but based on the table they are sitting at that date of time,

For now it worked for 1 reservation that I entered in manually in the database but when I create 2 reservations that are the same except for the reservation date my Total order price is getting summed up instead of creating a different `Total Order` amount for another date. Because they can take multiple orders the `Reservation_id` and table id keep coming back multiple times, so thats why I choose for the date to distinguish them from each other.

Here is my database structure:

```
MenuItem: 
    MenuItemID  int(11)         
    ItemName    varchar(255)        
    ItemPrice   double

orders:
 OrderID    int(11)         
 MenuItemID int(11)         
 ReceiptID  int(11)         
 Res_Datum  date            
 Tafel_Id   int(11)         
 Res_ID     int(11) 


receipt:
ReceiptID       int(11)         
ReceiptPrice    double

reserveringen:  
    Reservering_Id  int(11)         
    Tafel_Id        int(11)         
    VoorNaam        varchar(255)            
    AchterNaam      varchar(255)            
    TelefoonNummer  varchar(255)        
    Email           varchar(255)        
    Res_Datum       date

tafels:
    Tafel_Id        int(11)         
    tafel_Nummer    int(11)         
    Aantal_Personen int(11)
```

And this is the result I am getting:

```
Res_datum: 2019-01-21 ReservationID : 5 - Table_Number: 3 Total Order 
Price: 24
```

**Question:**
**I am wanting to get 2 different records, i got the exact same record in my orders table except for and order with a different date.
How do i do this?**

This is my php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "restaurant";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT O.Res_Datum,O.Res_ID, O.Tafel_Id, SUM(MI.ItemPrice) AS TotalReceiptPrice FROM Orders AS O INNER JOIN MenuItem AS MI ON O.MenuItemID = MI.MenuItemID ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Res_datum: ". $row["Res_Datum"]. " ReservationID : " . $row["Res_ID"]. " - Table_Number: " . $row["Tafel_Id"]. " Total Order Price: " . $row["TotalReceiptPrice"]." ". "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you want this?

```
SELECT O.Res_Datum, O.Res_ID, O.Tafel_Id, SUM(MI.ItemPrice) AS TotalReceiptPrice
FROM Orders AS O INNER JOIN MenuItem AS MI ON O.MenuItemID = MI.MenuItemID 
GROUP BY O.Res_Datum, O.Res_ID, O.Tafel_Id
```

This "groups" (GROUP BY) the records by date, reservation id, table id and thus gets the TotalReceiptPrice for any combination of (date, reservation id, table id).

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted!  Works perfectly